# PC with VPN, and then VM with proxy

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, proxy, privacy

For example I launched trusted VPN, it provides encrypted VPN tunnel.

Then I launch VM and enter proxy address in the settings of Internet Explorer.

So the question is - when I will use this virtual machine with proxy.... will my Internet Service Provider see anything about proxy address?

Or proxy address in this case will go through encrypted VPN tunnel and ISP will not see anything?

PS: by the way, what in total will see the proxy server about me? Just IP address of my VPN, and websites I visited, or something more?

Comment: If you set up your VM correctly, things will go thru VPN and ISP will see only encrypted packets going back and forth from VPN server.